# DocPad install hangs due to proxy

Tags: proxy, docpad

The `docpad install` command hangs probably due to my company proxy.

Npm runs properly only if I set the proxy like so:

```
npm config set http-proxy http://proxy.example.com:8080
npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.example.com:8080
```

Is there a similar configuration for DocPad?

Answer (score 0):

The `docpad install` command is exactly the same as `npm install` in recent releases, so you can just do that if it works and have no worries about not using `docpad install`.

As a side note, is there any documentation still referencing `docpad install`?

Comment: Ok, I was using a previous release. In recent release it hangs on the line: "Before we continue, have you read and agree to DocPad's Terms of Service (http://bevry.me/tos) and Privacy Policy (http://bevry.me/privacy)? [Y/n]" after choosing "Y" and pressing Enter. Any ideas?

Comment: Hrmmm, I've filed a bug here - https://github.com/bevry/docpad/issues/488 - and added a workaround. Will need to look into this further.